# OpenGL avoid calling glDrawElements multiple times

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I'm migrating our graphics ending from using the old fixed pipeline functions to making use of the programmable pipeline. Our simplest model is just a collection of points in space where each point can be represented by different shapes. One of these being a cube.

I'm basing my code off the cube [example](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/blob/master/src/indexedcube/indexedcube.cpp) from the OpenGL superbible.

In this example the cubes are placed at somewhat random places whereas I will have a fixed lit of points in space. I'm wondering if there is a way to pass that list to my shader so that a cube is drawn at each point vs looping through the list and calling glDrawElements each time. Is that even worth the trouble (performance wise)?

PS we are limited to OpenGL 3.3 functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is that even worth the trouble (performance wise)?

Probably yes, but try to profile nonetheless.

What you are looking for is *instanced rendering*, take a look at [glDrawElementsInstanced](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlDrawElementsInstanced) and [glVertexAttribDivisor](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlVertexAttribDivisor).

What you want to do is store the 8 vertices of a generic cube (centered on the origin) in one buffer, and also store the coordinates of the center of each cube in another vertex attribute buffer.

Then you can use `glDrawElementsInstanced` to draw N cubes taking the vertices from the first buffer, and translating them in the shader using the specific position stored in the second buffer.

Something like this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer( vertexPositionIndex, /** Blah .. */ );
glVertexAttribPointer( cubePositionIndex, /** Blah .. */ );
glVertexAttribDivisor( cubePositionIndex, 1 ); // Advance one vertex attribute per instance

glDrawElementsInstanced( GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices, NumberOfCubes );
```

In your vertex shader you need two attributes:

```
 vec3 vertexPosition; // The coordinates of a vertex of the generic cube
 vec3 cubePosition; // The coordinates of the center the specific cube being rendered

 // .... 
 vec3 vertex = vertexPosition + cubePosition;
```

Obviously you can have also a buffer to store the size of each cube, or another one for the orientation, the idea remains the same.

Comment: Just to put it out there, one could also use geometry shaders (since openGL 3.2) to generate cubes, but it might not be such a good solution performance-wise, especially for large amount of cubes. A bit older example (in favour of instancing) http://www.pixelnerve.com/v/2010/04/03/mass-cube-rendering/

Answer (score 0):

In your example every cube uses its own model matrix per frame.
If you want to keep that you need multiple drawElements calls.
If some cubes don't move (don't need a per frame model matrix) you should combine these cubes into one VBO.